# Como exibir tabela mesmo sem ter resultado?

Tags: php, jquery

Bom dia Pessoal,
Criei essa page para automatizar um processo na empresa:
http://pastebin.com/WdkdfWnN

Porém ela só exibi as tabelas bonitinhas somente quando há dados retornados na consulta, caso não há verifiquei no google chrome console retorna erro "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" e diagnostiquei que o problema é porque não existe dados retornados na consulta.
O código não está muito correto mais funciona somente quando há dados.
Como testar se existe dados ou não, pois eu add a condição IF mais pelo jeito não funciona, sempre retorna TRUE.

Comment: Sem o código não tem como ajudar, esse erro parece de javascript ...

Comment: O código está no pastebin, http://pastebin.com/WdkdfWnN

Comment: Experimente substituir em vez de `UNION`, coloque `UNION ALL`, e iguale os nomes dos campos, na tabela que não hover dados, coloque `NULL as nomeCampo` ou `0 as NumeCampo`, ou em vez de `UNION ALL`, apenas uma condição `IF(NomeCampo == NULL, 0,NomeCampo) as valor`. Você também pode criar uma condição de saída caso não tenha dado.

Comment: Pode executar uma outra query qualquer como: `select 'Nenhum dado' as campo1, 'Nenhum dado' as campo2, 'Nenhum dado' as campo3`;

Comment: Dêem uma olhada nessa pergunta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4255/%C3%89-uma-boa-id%C3%A9ia-colocar-o-c%C3%B3digo-no-pastebin-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-colocar-o-c%C3%B3digo-na-per

Comment: Me parece ser um erro ao usar o componente datatable. Você pode fazer uma verificação no php para caso não haja linhas retornadas na consulta, adicionar uma (ele precisa que tenha td dentro de todas as tr), com um texto do tipo: Não foram encontrados resultados".